# Tag Merge: quitting and resignation

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

**Proposal: merge [quitting](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quitting) into [resignation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resignation)**

Stats:

- [quitting](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quitting)

  - **Questions**: 160
  - **Tag Info**: *Questions about leaving one's job*
- [resignation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resignation)

  - **Questions**: 301
  - **Tag Info**: *For questions dealing with the voluntary parting of ways with a company. Questions can pertain to proper procedures to follow, etiquette for giving notice, or any other concerns relating to resignation. Note: questions in the style of "Should I resign..." are out of scope for Workplace.SE*
- [**Questions tagged with both**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quitting+resignation): 19

---

Quitting seems like an obvious synonym to resigning. I can't imagine substantially different interpretations. Users most likely tag their question with whichever of the two comes to mind first. Quite a few of the [top-voted questions for the quitting tag](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quitting?sort=votes&pageSize=30) are dual-tagged.

**In my opinion, the quitting tag serves no useful purpose and it should be merged into the resignation tag and set as a synonym.**

Comment: Here is the problem neither is a good tag for both.  Quitting is not necessarily resignation and vice versa.  I would support this if you can can come up with a tag synonym that does encompass both accurately and has the right feel for the site.

Comment: @Chad Well, Merriam-Webster defines to quit as "to give up employment" while resignation is defined as "an act of giving up a job or position in a formal or official way". Both seem to cover the act of an employee terminating his employment quite well. I would personally consider them synonyms though quitting is perhaps slightly more informal or emotional. Even if there is a significant distinction, I'm not sure it's worth having fragmented tags for a few hundred questions.

Comment: They are related but not the same.  I am sure there is a word that would encompass them both and be an appropriate tag.  Quitting is more about the leaving of the job where resignation is more about the act of informing management of the decision

Comment: Ha, yes. Resigning is just a nicer way of saying quitting.

Answer (score 7):

I hope these will be merged.

There are, as Chad points out, shades of difference between quitting and resigning.

However:

- I don't think our userbase makes that distinction when they're applying tags. Eyeballing them, I see answers

  - with both tags,
  - tagged resignation (not quitting) using the word quit
  - tagged quitting (not resignation) using the word resign
- the point of tags is to be useful for finding related questions and in almost all conceivable cases, the OP is considering both handing in their resignation and quitting the job, rather than doing one and not the other.

I cannot see a use case for keeping them separate.

Comment: I do not either but I would prefer some 3rd term that encompassed both. Like seperation or departure

Comment: Both quitting and resignation have to do with the employee deciding to leave their job. Separation and departure include dismissals, and I think most of the time, users explicitly distinguish between dismissal and resignation. I'm still struggling to see what the practical downside of merging into resignation is.

Comment: because the 2 things are as different as crash landing and regular landing.

Comment: The tag names still need to be things that users asking those questions will naturally type.  Those words seem to be "quitting" and "resigning" (or "resignation").  Tags don't have to be pedantically exacting; they need to function as buckets into which to group questions.  These all belong in one bucket and the names in use seem fine, barring a specific suggestion that's better without having unwanted connotations like "separation" does.